# Large binary file in IAR release configuration

Tags: binaryfiles, iar, firmware, size-reduction

I am debugging a firmware code and need to use the output .bin file for programming the hardware. In the debug configuration, the binary file size is 158 KB and in the release configuration, it goes down to 120 KB by applying the optimization settings in IAR Embedded Workbench.

I know that the file size can go down to below 50 KB as there are some old .bin files that the previous developer could get from the software. But I can't find a way to reduce the file size further.

Does anyone have any idea how the binary file size could be reduced in the release configuration in IAR Embedded Workbench?

Here's the ending lines of my map file:

```
  38 674 bytes of readonly  code memory
   4 721 bytes of readonly  data memory
  17 351 bytes of readwrite data memory

Errors: none
Warnings: none
```

Comment: Generate map file and see what uses the space. Then optimize and remove features until it fits.

Comment: I've never explored map files before. Can you elaborate or refer me to a link that explains the process or hints to it please? Thank you
I edited my question to include the last section of the map file.

Comment: Are you sure that map file is up-to-date? Those numbers add up to only ~43KB. Anyway, there is nothing special about the process: Just examine map file to see what functions and variables are biggest, and try to scale them down by optimizing. *But*, you should first find out where the space difference comes from. I suggest you to empty the build folder, and do complete rebuild. Generate new binary, map, object files etc. Everything.

Comment: Yeah, exactly! If you add them up, it is ~60KB. But the .hex file size is 120 KB. That's why I think there's some attachments to the file that I'm not aware of. Do your numbers always add up to the file size when you have external libraries?

Comment: Is it text file in [Intel HEX format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX)? If yes, then it's understandable. One byte is written with 2 hex digits, so file can be twice as big as the plain binary size. This should not be an issue, since typically the flashing software does the conversion from text back to binary when you write the file to device.